# Import CrossCompile CMake project to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, cmake, raspberry-pi, cross-platform

I' struggling with importing a CMake project to Eclipse...
I have a CMake project imported from SVN; this works fine on the Raspi (after adapting some pathes in the CMakeCache.txt file. I do have no real experience with CMake, so I guess this is already a wrong approach :-).
What I actually want to do is compiling it on my linux machine with Eclipse because it is a little bit more comfortable. Cross compiling for the Raspi works fine with a simple C-project, but now I have severe problems in setting up a CMake project in Eclipse.
What I have done until now: I just imported the whole project from SVN into Eclipse and adapted the existing CMakeCache.txt file (adapted the pathes to the project and to the compiler etc...). Compiling stops with an error telling me that the library udev is not found. Hahaha, obviously CMake is looking for the libraries on my machine and not in the libraries for the Raspi.

So how do I tell CMake where to look for the "correct" libraries? Or more general: how do I set up a CMake project in Eclipse imported via SVN (no Eclipse project!)? As far as I experienced until now is that CMake is quite allmighty, but everything else than intuitive ;-). Especially in combination with Eclipse...and with SVN...

Thanks a lot!!

Greetings

Meffy

Comment: `obviously CMake is looking for the libraries on my machine and not in the libraries for the Raspi.` - for cross compiling you need to use appropriate [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html).

Comment: @Tsyvarev As I mentioned I'm quite new to CMake. I read something about the toolchain file and of course there are a lot of examples for Raspi toolchain files. What I dont't quite understand: in the existing CMakeCache.txt if have e.g. an entry `CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/home/blabla/rpi_toolchain/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`, and in the toolchain file would be an entry `SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER
/home/blabla/rpi_toolchain/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)`. Wouldn't this collide?

Comment: Yes, setting compiler is one purpose of toolchain file. But it also needs for adjust search path for libraries, tools, and some other things.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So it would have no influence if I have duplicate information? So just for curiousity: which information would be used if I had two different compilers given in the toolchain file and the CMakeCache.txt file?